# How to "Reset Picture" in Power point Slide using VBA macro?

Tags: image, vba, excel, powerpoint

I am generating power point presentation using Excel. The macro is running excel. It is working perfectly fine. Issues is the Excel macro pasted the pictures with strange format. I have to use manually the command of "Reset Picture" by right clicking on each picture-->Picture format--> Reset picture

Is it possible to make a macro power point which can do the reset picture command automatically for me?

THanking you advance
Best regards

```
 'getting name of picture from Excel sheet cell

 logopic = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jan 2015").Range("z" & CellNr).Value
 apic = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jan 2015").Range("aa" & CellNr).Value
 mpic = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jan 2015").Range("ab" & CellNr).Value
```

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jan 2015").Range("z" & CellNr) > 0 Then

' here we are copying the pictures of logo in the respective slides

```
 oPP1.Slides(2).Shapes.AddPicture("" & FolderPath & "\" & logopic &    ".jpg", msoFalse, msoCTrue, 10, 10, 60, 45).Apply
```

Comment: Would help to show the code which is doing the pasting into PPT

Comment: As Tim says, show us the current code you've got.  And it might help to explain what you mean by "strange format".  Wild guess, though:  if you're using code to add a picture shape by inserting a picture from a file, use -1, -1 as the height and width coordinates.  That might be all you need.

Comment: THanks ...here is the code:

Comment: @haplc as Steve pointed, use -1,-1 for the height and width parameter then the image will maintain the aspect ratio. I don't understand why you have `Apply` call since that applies the a formatting that has been picked up. You can remove that as well if it is not intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Record the steps in powerpoint's macro recorder. That will give you the basic code to paste into your excel macro. Alt T, M, R to start, same keys to stop recording. Then Alt + F11 to open Powerpoint's VBA editor to find the code.

Also have a look at Paste Special command where you choose the format to be pasted.

This is an answer I give about doing the same in VBA - VBS. For you it's easier as it's VBA - VBA. Make sure powerpoint in in the References in Excel.

> Record the steps in excel macro recorder. You have to rewrite it a bit because it uses a type of syntax that vbs doesn't.
>
> This applies (I don't have a medium9) xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 in vba.

```
Selection.AutoFormat Format:=xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4, Number:=True, _
    Font:=True, Alignment:=True, Border:=True, Pattern:=True, Width:=True
```

> So first look up constants in vba's object browser. xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 = 17
>
> Then look the function up in object browser and look at the bottom for the function definition,.

```
Function AutoFormat([Format As XlRangeAutoFormat = xlRangeAutoFormatClassic1], [Number], [Font], [Alignment], [Border], [Pattern], [Width])
```

> So the vba becomes in vbs (and vbs works in vba) (and as you can see you can work out the correct way without needing to look the function up usually)

```
Selection.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

> So your code becomes

```
objXLWs.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

> You are using Excel and you can record it in Excel and have Excel write your code.
>
> Alt + T, M, R
>
> then Home key then Up Arrow. Stop recording.
>
> Look what Excel wrote

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

> or if you had of recorded Go To dialog

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

> or if you had of recorded Ctrl + Home

```
Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: Note that PowerPoint no longer has a macro recorder.  Hasn't since PPT 2003.

Comment: That's my version. Why not?

Comment: I have tried to use the code you have given. Issues facing are: I dont have record macro function in my power point. FInd that out it is not more available after power point 2010. I have updated code I am using in Excel in my question. WOuld really appreciate if you can advise how to insert picture in power point with original format using the excel macro given above. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is what Macro Recorder recordered in PPT 2003.Colons indicate a line ending in VB. `With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange:.Fill.Visible = msoFalse:.Fill.Solid:.Fill.Transparency = 0#:.Line.Visible = msoFalse:End With` So it appears there is no specific command for reset but a sequence of commands.

Comment: I think recoirding would still be in PPT 2013. The editor and everything else is (although hidden). PowerPoint 2010/2013:
File

**2013** Click File then PowerPoint options... at the bottom of the menu that appears

Click Trust Center on the left of the PowerPoint Options dialog box, then click Trust Center Settings on right.
Click Macro Settings on the left of the dialog. •Press ALT+F11 to start the VBA editor. 
•Or choose File | Options | Customize Ribbon and put a checkmark next to Developer in the listbox under Customize Ribbon. from http://www.pptfaq.com FAQ

Comment: Sorry, but no.  There's no macro recorder in PPT 2010 or 2013, though the VBA editor is there in both.  BTW, I wrote the article that you cite.  ;-)

Comment: The full URL was too long to paste.

Comment: You may *think* macro recording's still in PPT 2013.  I *know* it's not.  You've quoted an explanation of how to get into the VBA editor.  That's not the macro recorder.  Unless you *have* 2013 and can give step by step instructions for recording a macro, it might be best to take it on faith that the recorder's no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub InsertPictureExample()

    ' This inserts a picture at "natural" size on
    ' Slide 1 of the current active presentation

    Dim oSh As Shape

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        Set oSh = .Shapes.AddPicture("c:\temp\thing.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1)
        ' position the shape if desired:
        oSh.Left = 100
        oSh.Top = 100
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, But it is still not working. Is there any specfic setting I have to make in the jpeg file?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  What happens that shouldn't?  What doesn't happen that should?

Comment: Following should happen: the pictures should be inserted at defined points and in the original format. THe pictures are being inserted in the power point slides, issue is they picture are inserted with the bad format, part os the pictures are cut, stretched . That is why I have to use RESET picture for every picture in every slide.

Comment: Sorry, but:  "the pictures should be inserted at defined points" ... what defined points?  Defined how?  And ... "and in the original format. THe pictures are being inserted in the power point slides, issue is they picture are inserted with the bad format,"  What does bad format mean?

Comment: I try to clearify: "defined points: the points which I have defined in the command in VBA:  oPP1.Slides(2).Shapes.AddPicture("" & FolderPath & "\" & apic & ".jpg", msoFalse, msoCTrue, 400, 150).Apply

Comment: "Bad format". What to say that after running the macro, pictures are being inserted but either are cut from top, or they are stretched. For example, I would like to insert a logo of the company: my expectation, the picture inserted should be as the logo appears in the customer document. Hope I am clear enough? thanks

Comment: One thought:  Make sure that the slide you're adding the picture to does not have an empty Content or Picture placeholder on it.  Some versions of PPT will automatically place new pictures into one if these rather than inserting them as regular pictures.  That can mess things up.

Comment: what a great thought :) prefect. This was the issue: Now the code is generating right pictures with right format. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great!  For content placeholders, it's pretty easy to write a function that tests for empty ones and adds a bit of consistent gibberish text.  Or if they have known gibberish text, deletes same (to empty the placeholder again afterwards.  You'd use that before and after adding your picture.